# I need to find sum of N digit numbers

Tags: c++

I need to write a program which counts `n` digit number sum. For example, sum of 1 digit number is 45 (from 1 to 9) and so on.

I wrote this code but it's useless so I need little bit help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    long suma = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        suma = suma + i;
    }
    cout << suma;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basically you need a way to determine what is an N digit number.

Comment: What is wrong with your program? You need to be more clear? As written, if you type 9, you will get the sum from 1 to 9. Do you want instead to have that sum if we enter 1? If so, would entering 2 should give the sum from 10 to 99? and so on?

Comment: yes Phil I need to write 1 and get sum 2 and etc

Comment: Do you need to do a loop because computing the sum of number in a range (a to b inclusively) is trivial mathematics: `(a + b) * (b - a + 1) / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you're missing is a way to determine *what an N digit number is*. Fortunately you know that N-digit number ranges from 10^(N-1) to 10^N, so you have this as the loop condition:

```
#include <cmath>

for (long i = pow(10, n-1); i < pow(10, n); i++)
```

If you want to do this faster, you need some Maths work beforehand and rework the algorithm. You probably want the summing formula:

```
a = pow(10, n-1);
b = pow(10, n);
sum = (a + b - 1) * (b - a) / 2; // (a1 + an)* n / 2
```

Comment: its working kinda, but I am getting time limit error so I need to optimize my code somehow..

Comment: It should work but not very efficiently. At the very least, you should compute the upper bound only once (10 * lower bound).

Comment: @Phil1970 Turn on `-O2` and trust your compiler.

Comment: Updated answer is pretty quick. +1

Comment: `5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 26`. 
`(5 + 8 - 1) * (8 - 5) / 2 = 12 * 3 / 2 = 18`
Thus your formula is not exact...

Comment: @Phil1970 `5 + 6 + 7 = 18` it's right. The upper bound is not inclusive.

Comment: @iBug You are right. I didn't pay attention to that. Nevertheless, another easy optimization would be `b = 10 * a`

Comment: `pow` is designed to compute nasty stuff like e to the power of pi. Using it to compute exponents of 10 is overkill and likely to be very slow. Plus it operates on  floating point numbers so you'll have precision errors as the number get larger.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to find the sum of N digit numbers:

```
include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    long suma = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (long i = pow(10, n-1); i < pow(10, n); i++) // this is what was wrong in your approach,
    {
        suma = suma + i;
    }
    cout << suma;
    return 0;
}

OR

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,x,y;
    long suma = 0;
    cin >> n;
    x =pow(10,n-1);
    y =pow(10,n);
    suma = (x + (y-1)) * (x - y) / 2;  //this will reduce your time complexity from O(n) by eliminating the for loop.
    cout << suma;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: a good answer explains what you did and why. Otherwise you have  a Code Only answer and the asker gets little more than a marginal improvement to their cut and paste skills. Also note that `pow` operates on floating point numbers and will result in precision errors as the numbers get larger.